# Create JS Regex for URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

How to create a regex to target this url?

```
example.com/words-and-12.3-numerals/x12345
```

1. example.com always remains the same.
2. Middle section may contain uppercase, lowercase, hyphens, decimal points and numerals.
3. Last section uses a specific letter "x" and five numerals.

Comment: how about /(example.com/)(.*)(/x\d{5}/i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` indicate start of string.
`example\.com` will match it exactly.
`\/` will match the slash. 
`[a-zA-Z0-9-.]` match as you said in requirement.
`\/` next slash. 
`x\d{5}` x and 5 digits.
`$` end of string.

```
/^example\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+\/x\d{5}$/
```

Comment: @WesFoster Edited. Since I am on mobile it takes some time. Thanks for the patience